# Weighted sum of negative binomial distributions - approximate fast parameter calculation

Tags: negative-binomial-distribution, approximation, convolution, parameterization, method-of-moments

Let's suppose we have a convolution (weighted sum) of three negative binomials (parameterised as mean and overdispersion).

```
NB(mu1, size1) * 0.1 + NB(mu2, size2) * 0.3 + NB(mu3, size3) * 0.6
```

Is there an approximate calculation of the resulting mu_mix and size_mix?

For mu_mix it's easy, being:

```
mu1 * 0.1 + mu2 * 0.3 + mu3 * 0.6
```

For size, however, I am not sure on how to proceed.

The method I'm looking for should be direct and non-recursive if possible, as I have to use it inside a Bayes inference model.

Comment: A convolution and a weighted sum (i.e. a mixture) a two fairly different things. As I understand you want to approximate a *mixture* of negative binomials with another negative binomial. The word "convolution" would then be misleading.

Comment: Changed the title. Yes convolution indicates a sum (https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1035210/convolution-of-negative-binomial-distribution), I didn't used mixture because in Bayesian statistics people generally refer to a mixture as a mixture model (e.g., bimodal).

Answer (score 3):

The negative binomial has a fairly simple characteristic function, so the weighted sum also has a fairly simple characteristic function.  [Davies (1973](https://www.jstor.org/stable/2334555)) described how to invert this to get the cdf or density.

Davies' method is one of the standard approaches to weighted sums of $\chi^2$ distributions, so it does have genuine usefulness. But it does take some programming.